# keras LSTM: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm building a very simple NN made of 1 LSTM layer. The code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(15, return_sequences = True, return_state = True)
sample_hidden = tf.zeros((1000, 15))
x = tf.zeros((1000, 100, 10))
y, h, c = lstm(x, initial_state=sample_hidden)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: An `initial_state` was passed that is not compatible with `cell.state_size`. Received `state_spec`=ListWrapper([InputSpec(shape=(1000, 15), ndim=2)]); however `cell.state_size` is [15, 15]
```

I don't understand why the cell.state_size is [15,15]. However, even when I tried to input an array of zeros having this size, I still get the same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

initial state should include h & c, not h only. Editing the code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf    
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(15, return_sequences = True, return_state = True)
h = tf.zeros((1000, 15))
c = tf.zeros((1000, 15))
x = tf.zeros((1000, 100, 10))
y, h, c = lstm(x, initial_state=[h, c])
```

This will remove the error.

Just posting the answers for anyone who gets stuck in the same problem